# Combining two regex functions to strip html tags

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to get the H1 text within html pages I used a regex which worked fine until we started using microformats on some pages for simplicity, I used the title of the page (the h1 tag as the "item being reviewed).

The problem is that my regex I used before stopped working so I wrote another regex to be executed in case the first returned an empty result. This is very awrkward I know!!! How can I combine the following into one simple regex? :

```
//Get the H1 title
function get_tag( $attr, $value, $xml )
{
   $attr = preg_quote($attr);
   $value = preg_quote($value);

   $tag_regex2 = '/<h1>(.*?)<\\/h1>/si';
   $tag_regex = '/<h1><span itemprop="itemreviewed">(.*?)<\\/span><\\/h1>/si';


   preg_match($tag_regex,
   $xml,
   $matches);

   if ($matches[1] == ""){
   preg_match($tag_regex2,
   $xml,
   $matches);
   };



   return $matches[1];
}
```

Comment: It's 2013. Stop trying to parse HTML with regular expressions.

Comment: @Alex: I've been in your shoes. Trust me, take this down before everyone downvotes this.

Comment: If i need a quick fix for something, and if i will use it only once, i'm still using this :D

Comment: BTW , if we say "don't use regex for this" , we should give him some ideas. For example you can use DOM parsers (like Simple PHP Dom Parser) to solve your problem.

Comment: Why won't `strip_tags` work?

Comment: @cwallenpoole That would strip all the tags, I suspect he wants to remove only h1 ?

Comment: @Alex You should escape `/` like this `\/`. Also using `preg_quote()` on the subject doesn't make sense, remove those 2 lines. `preg_quote()` is used for your regular expressions, not the strings that we are matching against.

Comment: Thanks everyone! Ok so regex is not a brilliant idea what is the correct efficient way???!

Comment: @Alex - Use an XML parser.

Answer (score 3):

If you're willing to sacrifice robustness for convenience (which you must be if you're using regex to parse HTML :)), you could use

```
$tag_regex = '#<h1>(?:<span itemprop="itemreviewed">)?(.*?)(?:</span>)?</h1>#si';
```

Comment: You. I like you. You handle these things way better than most people.

Answer (score 1):

`/<h1>(?:<[^>]+>)?(.*?)(?:<[^>]+>)?<\/h1>/si` would work in general for removing tags within the `<h1/>`, but you'll probably want to customize it a bit.  If you want to remove the `span` listed above in particular it would look something like `/<h1>(?:<span\s+itemprop=["']itemreviewed["'][^>]*>)?(.*?)(?:<[^>]+>)?<\/h1>/si`.  Check out [RegularExpressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) for a great reference.

Comment: Nice thanks I can use this for other stuff! Ok so I get it that parsing HTML is not the best idea!